# SSIS Package download from Excel

Tags: sql-server, package, type-conversion, ssis-2012

Using SSIS I am downloading data from an Excel file into a MS SQL database. In this Excel file, there's a column with data looking like `99,99`, which goes into a column of type `float` in the database. After downloading to the database, the data in this column has ignored the comma and it has become `9999`.

Any suggestions on how to correctly download the data into my database and keep the comma?

Comment: Do you want to store the data using a comma rather than a . or do you want it changed to a .   99,99 or 99.99

Comment: I just have no idea why this comma ignoring while its downloading....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the locale settings on the SSIS server are consistent with those of the Excel. Specifically look at the thousand separator and the decimal separator. If SSIS thinks the comma is a thousand-separator, it is ignored.

You could also make a `Derived Column Transformation`, in which you import this column from Excel as text, change the `,`into a `.`using a string replace function, and then cast it to `float`.